# Pdf viewer with page-per-sheet print setting

Tags: linux, pdf, gui, printing

Is there a program that - when printing - provides an option for the number of pages to be printed per sheet?

---

I know about [this](https://superuser.com/questions/246092/how-to-convert-a-1-page-pdf-to-a-2-page-per-sheet-pdf) CLI solution, but I want a GUI. Can I have a such option or the document must be modified first?

Evince and Master PDF Editor don't seem have this option. Does Okular? (I'm asking in Xfce and Okular comes with a lot of dependencies anyway).

Comment: PDF, GUI edit, UNIX - pick two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) provides this setting, somewhat hidden in the printer properties. As most viewers just use some native printer dialog you may find it there in your favorite viewer, too.

[image]

**Addendum**:

- Looking up **Evince**, the option is under **Print -Page setup - Pages per side**.

[image]

- **[PDF Studio Viewer](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/download/)** has the option:

[image]

---

- Considering **Master PDF Editor**, it has that setting in the printer Properties, but it is active only for a real printer, while it is disabled for the "Print to file (PDF)" option.
- **LibreOffice Draw** can be used to view, print, and export PDF files, and it has this option too (*Print - Page layout - Pages per sheet*).

Comment: do those options appear after you press "Print" in the first window?

Comment: No, press the "Properties" button right of the printer selection.

Comment: I have accepted your answer (**"most viewers just use some native printer dialog you may find it there in your favorite viewer, too"**); please accept my future edits as I try to add info on other programs involved.

Answer (score 1):

I am still expecting an answer in case there is a pdf viewer with that option, but for the moment I can confirm the `pdfnup` command, which can be integrated to Thunar custom actions and thus operate through a GUI.

Testing `pdfnup` terminal command (from [here](https://superuser.com/a/948095/162573)) in Linux Mint Xfce it said the needed tool was not installed and recommended `texlive-extra-utils`. After installing that, it still gave an error complaining of some missing LaTex package. I found [here](http://rcdocarv.blogspot.fr/2014/04/pdfjam-error-latex-package-pdfpagessty.html) that the error can be fixed by installing `texlive-latex-recommended`. After installing that it all went fine.

So, to use in terminal: open terminal in the location of *your.pdf* and run `pdfnup your.pdf`.

Or in Thunar custom actions, add the command `pdfnup %f`. Appearance conditions: check "other files"

[image]

and restrict to pdf under "file pattern".

[image]

This will create a new file called *your-nup.pdf* where two pages from before will be integrated on one single page **from left to right**.

If you need **four** per page, 2x2 (not all four from left to right, but 1-2 above and 3-4 below on the same sheet), use the command `pdfnup --nup 2x2 %f` (indicated in a comment under the answer linked above).

Comment: Interesting solution!